# ext plugin not working in liferay 6.1.2 jboss7

Tags: deployment, liferay, jboss7.x, liferay-6

I created an **ext-plugin** for extending Liferay LDAP **DefaultPortalToLDAPConverter**. I created an ext plugin in eclipse. In the `ext-impl/src/main/java/com/liferay/portal/security/ldap/CustomPortalToLDAPConverter` i extended `DefaultPortalToLDAPConverter` and **kept only the changed methods** in my class. Also I added in `ext-spring.xml`

```
<bean id="portalToLDAPConverter" class="com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.CustomPortalToLDAPConverter" />
```

and then deployed the ext. The deployment went well without any errors. But the changes did not take place. Is there anything wrong in what I am doing? I use **jboss7.1.1-final bundled Liferay6.1.2**. I build using maven and then **deploy by placing the war file in liferay-home/deploy**. Then I tried restarting the server. Now I could see that my ext-spring.xml is missing in the jar file. Is there any specific reason for this? Please help.

Comment: silly question but did you restart after the deployment was successful? Also can you check if your class is present in `ext-<project-name>-impl.jar` in `/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/`. How are you checking if the change is taking place or not. Also can you check if this works in tomcat? Thanks

Comment: IIRC one of the limitations of ext plugins is that you have to restart the server - merely deploying it is not enough. Did you try that?

Comment: I am sorry that I didnt mention. I restarted the server several times. I have edited the question. Now I found that my ext-spring.xml is missing in the jar.

Comment: I found out the issue. I checked the tutorials and saw that the META-INF was to be placed in src/main and in some other tutorial that in src/main/java. It was not working. I places as usual in the src/main/resources folder and it worked. I don't know if thats the right thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the tutorials say that the META-INF should be placed in the ext-impl/src or ext-impl/src/main folder. Doing so was not placing my ext-spring.xml in the jar build. Shifting the jar to ext-impl/src/main/resources helped and the META-INF was detected. Upon restarting, the changes took effect.

Answer (score 0):

Not compiled files that are meant to be put inside of class-path of resulting artifact should be placed in main/resources path: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR